# Why Qt application title is followed by application path on screen reader?

Tags: qt, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I have a simple application in Qt that has a `QMainWindow` and a `QWebEngineView` that loads an html page. I've set the `QApplication` name and the `QMainWindow` title.

```
app.setApplicationName("FooApp");
window.setWindowTitle("FooApp Window");
```

When I use a screen reader, it will read the main window title as:

> FooApp C:/Users/tulio/Desktop/TestApp//bin/debug/test.exe

**I just need it to read the application name, how can I do this?**

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  a.setApplicationName("FooApp");

  MainWindow w;
  w.setWindowTitle("FooApp Window");
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLayout>
#include <QApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent) {
  this->layout()->addWidget(&web_view_);
  this->layout()->setMargin(0);

  this->resize(QSize(1000, 700));

  QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/index.html";
  qDebug() << QString("HTML Path %1").arg(path);

  web_view_.page()->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
  web_view_.resize(this->size());

  channel_.registerObject("Test", &test_);
  web_view_.page()->setWebChannel(&channel_);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {

}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
  web_view_.resize(event->size());
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QWebChannel>
#include <QDebug>

class Test : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Test(QObject *parent=0) : QObject(parent) {}
  virtual ~Test() {}
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();
private:
  QWebEngineView web_view_;
  QWebChannel channel_;
  Test test_;
protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**teste.pro**

```
QT       += core gui webengine webenginewidgets webchannel

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = teste
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [accessibleDescription : QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#accessibleDescription-prop) [accessibleName : QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#accessibleName-prop) which holds the desciption that gets accessed by assistive technologies.